# how to use a separate table for activity on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using Rails 4.2.6 and Postgres 9.4.

I have a Queryable table which we for managing querying data. It has about 20k rows and several different models converge at this point. We have the ability to "rebuild" the table (ie deleting everything in it and recreating it). However, this takes about 20 minutes and don't do it on production.

Is there a way to tell our Queryable model to build a copy at like 'queryables_future' and rebuild the table there and when completed, delete our current 'queryables' table and rename 'queryables_future' to 'queryables'? Or any other proposed workaround?

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do this without at least _some_ downtime so why bother doing it this way instead of just clearing the table?

Comment: Anyway, a slightly different approach would be to just write a Rake task that renames the `Queryable` table (from, say, _queryables_ to _queryables_archive_) and then builds the `Queryable` table again, no?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that it takes about 20 min to build. I'd rather build in background and then switch both of them - hence no downtime

Comment: 20 minutes to build an [empty] table? :O

Comment: Cleaning the table is a possibility but it's complicated by having to know all the potential edge cases. I'd prefer to do both strategies but the rebuilding strategy is done with the exception of removing downtime. Wondering if I could self.table_name in a before_create if a flag is set

Comment: 20 min to populate it

Comment: You mean start putting new records into a new table? Why not just use `self.table_name`, then, in your `Queryable` model? What would a `before_create` macro buy you, let alone the flag?

Comment: ended up just adding an is_valid flag on the queryables table and running the 20 minute job. At end, I delete out invalid (is_valid='f') records.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you would do in a queued background job using a tool such as Sidekiq. Background jobs run in a separate process than your main web application, so it takes some configuration and effort to set them up, but they're immensely powerful once you do.

This is a rather broad subject so I'd recommend checking out these links:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq